# How to customize TinyMCE upload UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I want to customize my Tinymce UI.
When I click upload image button,
I will get a Insert/edit image div,
But I don't need general , only need upload.

[upload image UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eabxO.png)

How can I do?

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: false,
        plugins: 'image emoticons',
        toolbar: 'image emoticons',
        force_br_newlines : false,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '',
        branding: false,
        statusbar : false,
        setup: function (editor) {
              editor.on('change', function () {
                  editor.save();
              });
          },
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            success('http://moxiecode.cachefly.net/tinymce/v9/images/logo.png');
        },
  });
```

Comment: You need to add your code so we can see what you have done thus far. Also, it will help you to read through this documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry , my mistake.I update it,Thank you!

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

For the future references - I find how to remove Image description & Dimensions - by

```
...
toolbar: 'image',
+
image_dimensions: false,
image_description: false,
+
force_br_newlines : false,
...
```

(I add text between plus (+) signs. It looks like this: [TinyMCE Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/thgaab) )

There is way to remove advanced tab by option **image_advtab** set to false, so maybe there is similar way to remove general, but I don't find it on ([TinyMCE docs](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/)) or in source code.

Comment: I do the same thing...Thank a lot , still can't find any method to remove it.